# Equivalence of Horn formulas tractable?

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, satisfiability, propositional-logic

Assume I have two [Horn formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) $\phi_1, \phi_2$.   Horn formulas are CNF formulas so that each clause has at most one unnegated literal.  For example:

$x_1 \wedge (\neg x_1 \vee \neg x_2 \vee x_3 )\wedge (x_3 \vee \neg x_4)$

I want to decide whether $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are logically equivalent, i.e., $\phi_1 \leftrightarrow \phi_2$.  Equivalently, I want to test whether  $F=(\phi_1 \vee \neg\phi_2)\wedge (\neg \phi_1 \vee \phi_2)$ is true for all assignments of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

Is this problem tractable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check equivalence in polynomial time (in fact, in quadratic time).

By similar logic to [my answer to your previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/128422/755), it suffices to test satisfiability of $\phi_1 \land \neg c$ where $c$ ranges over the clauses of $\phi_2$.  If any of these are satisfiable, then $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are inequivalent.  Otherwise, if they're all unsatisfiable, and the same for $\phi_2 \land \neg c'$ where $c'$ ranges over all clauses of $\phi_1$, then $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are equivalent.

So, let's investigate how to test satisfiability of $\phi_1 \land \neg c$ where $c$ is a clause of $\phi_2$.  By assumption, $c$ is a Horn clause, so it has the form $\neg x_1 \lor \dots \lor \neg x_k \lor x_{k+1}$.  So, $\phi_1 \land \neg c$ has the form

$$\phi_1 \land x_1 \land \dots \land x_k \land \neg x_{k+1}.$$

This turns out to be a Horn formula, so you can its test satisfiability with [the standard algorithm for testing satisfiability of Horn formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability).  This takes linear time per clause, and there are linearly many clauses, so the total running time is quadratic.